# Flask: how to "connect" subprocess script to running context to make response

Tags: python, http, flask, exception

I've already read most of the existing StackOverflow questions about Flask contexts and error handling and response, but I can't figure out how can I `abort(make_response)` from outside the current process.

I do a system call to another Python script (yes, this can be confusing, but I need to do it, because I need to execute this Python script by a legacy application called "Genesis" (used to PCB design). The system call is:

```
sh_command = ["/home/genesis/call", "-x", f"-s{_python_script.py}", "--script_parameters", parameters]
run_instance = subprocess.run(sh_command)
```

On my `_python_script.py`, I've tried:

```
with app.app_context():
    message = {
        "code": 500,
        "message": {
            "status": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
    abort(make_response("Error", "500"))
```

But I get this error message:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException: ??? Unknown Error: None
```

How can I throw a response to the current app?

Comment: Wouldn't you just call the external script in a route handler and then check the processes return value. Depending on what it returns you either respond normally or with an error.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply.

I can do that, but I want to use my error handle from inside the called script.

Comment: You won't be able to. All you can do is to have the calling code interpret a result code of some sort.

Comment: I solve this problem with a shared output log file. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post your solution?